# Callouts lines gets changed while the screen size is different

Tags: highcharts

We use extensively to generate our graphs and currently trying to add a callout to our graphs.

The callouts has a box and a arrow line. The arrow line indicates a particular point and the box contains the messages.

I line is identified in a particular point in the graph and I use the topixel method to generate the point.

The lines gets displaced badly depending on the size of the screen.

Here is my fiddle code:-

https://jsfiddle.net/cucjw7xc/11

and here is the graph which shows a displaced line in windows machine that one of our user uses.
Not sure how I can set the length of the lines as each machine has different screen size.

Bigger screen(screen height-1080 & width - 1920)

[image]

Smaller screen(where its displayed correctly, screen height - 900 & width - 1440)

[image]

Code:
My javascript is given in the fiddle and its too big to attach here.

```
  <div class="row">
            <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @morganfree The same code can be used in different screen size to see the difference. I have attached the screen shot.